# How do I check if someone is logged on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh

Given a machine name, I want to check if someone's logged in on that machine or not. Just a yes/no answer would be sufficient (I don't want their username). Any hints on what command to look for?

By 'logged in' - I mean using a graphical UI on that machine - ssh doesn't count.

You can assume that I have an authorized ssh login for this machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`who` shows you who is logged in.  If they are in a gui, their "terminal" is the X display they are attached to (otherwise the tty):

```
paul     :0           2013-02-20 11:43
```

So

```
who | grep paul
```

would return nothing if I wasn't logged in, or something if I was.

If you wanted to exclude ssh and console connections, then:

```
who | grep -v pts | grep paul
```

You can run this command remotely by adding to the ssh command:

```
ssh user@host 'who | grep -v pts | grep paul'
```

This will log into the remote machine, do the `who`, and return the results.

Comment: That looks good! I'm assuming you need to ssh into the machine first - and then run 'who' - is that correct? Or can I use 'who' (or some other incarnation of it) locally and check the status on remote machines?

Comment: @UtkarshSinha I have added a bit at the end to run it remotely.  This kind of thing works best if using public keys instead of passwords for ssh, so you don't need to enter a password.